# Inject custom function to onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io, jquery-events

What I'm trying to do is to record all user activity on a given web page, so I'm using `socket.io` to send the events registered on the page, to the server with something like this:

```
$(document).on('click.mynamespace', function(event){
    var elem = event.target;
    socket.emit('my-message', { 'element' : elem };
}
```

The problem I'm facing is when the target element is a link of this kind `<a href="#" onclick="someFunctionThatRedirects()">My link</a>`. Whatever function is called and the page unloads (disconnecting my socket) before the `socket.emit` statement is executed properly.

I want to make this as universal as possible since this will be working as a plugin, and would like it to adjust to any kind of environment over which I will have no control.

So, is there a way to "highjack" all click events, send them first with my custom function, and then continue with the "normal" execution, whatever it may be?

**EDIT**

It seems only FF (tested on `14.0.1`) causes the `socket.emit` event not to finish. Chrome `21.0.x` seems to be working but not sure if this is by "chance".

**EDIT 2**

The function `someFunctionThatRedirects` actually redirects in this way `window.location.ref = clickedurl`

Comment: As a side note, the wrapping and direct unwrapping is superfluous. `event.target` is what you're after for `elem`.

Comment: You can defer the redirect to after the click event

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry, not sure why I wrote the [0] stuff. @pimvdb

Answer (score 0):

Events bubble upwards, so clicked element gets it's event fired before your `socket.emit`, you can change the way the functions work to make them do their actions in the order you want as follows

```
function someFunctionThatRedirects(){
    window.redirectTo = 'myNewPage';
}
$(document).on('click.mynamespace', function(event){
    var elem = $(event.target)[0];
    socket.emit('my-message', { 'element' : elem };
    if(window.redirectTo !== undefined) window.location.href = window.redirectTo;
}
```

Comment: This arguably doesn't play nicely with the "as universal as possible since this will be working as a plugin" idea.

Comment: Exactly, as @pimvdb states, I have no control over this function, or any other that may end up there, for that matter. It works nicely on all other links so far, only on this particular case that has an inline function that does the whole redirecting.

Comment: Well you could add your function to also listen for `beforeunload` but it is a different event type so I don't know if you'll get the data you want to record.

Comment: `$(event.target)[0] === event.target`.

Comment: That was copied forward from original question

Comment: @MathiasBynens any thoughts on the original question?